# What's the worst implication of this apache configuration issue?

Tags: apache

The following error message appears when I start apache2:

```
apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 10.168.103.11 for ServerName
```

What's the worst thing that becomes possible due to this misconfiguration, assuming that the application Apache's serving is well written (can this result in information disclosure of the IP, assuming the apache server's behind a load balancer, for example)?

I'm assuming there can be *some* deleterious consequences, otherwise the message wouldn't have been written to `error.log` to begin with.

(I'm curious about the answer for both Apache 2.2 and Apache 2.4.)

Comment: A 10.x address will not be routed in the Internet. Are you concerned about an IP address leak in a corporate network?

Comment: @ThomasWeller I'm concerned about leaking a private IP from behind the firewall / loadbalancer due to the utility that IP has in guessing network size and the probable location of other hosts on the network. So if, for example, the backend application or another application on the same subnet has a flaw whereby it can be used as a proxy to internal hosts, an attacker who knows the address "10.168.103.11" knows that it would probably make the most sense to start scanning the 10.168.103.0/24 range first, and that (while it's possible) the network's unlikely to be larger than 10.168.0.0/16.

Comment: They can use this information to minimize the number of requests made and maximize the likelihood that they'll be able to find another internal host to work with before the NIDS picks up on weird traffic.

Comment: They can also use this kind of information to determine other things. For example, if the address is 192.168.56.11, they can know they're probably dealing with a VirtualBox VM. If the IP address is 192.168.0.9, and they're dealing with the relatively-new server of a large company, they can be reasonably sure that server is on a partition separate from the larger corporate network (which would otherwise run out of IPs, or at least it would be unlikely that the last 16 bits would be such a low number).

Comment: And I'm curious whether there are any parts of Apache itself which may rely on the ServerName variable and fail in subtle or silent ways when it doesn't agree with the `Host` header.